# Jenkins continuous deployment error

Tags: git, jenkins

I am learning Jenkins CI test & deploy as stated in the excellent tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511

at the end of the tutorial, it should handle the deployment of the app...
as per the deploy script and the Jenkins project config w ./script/deploy

```
#!/bin/sh
 ssh app@my.server.ip <<EOF
  cd ~/hello-jenkins
  git pull
  npm install --production
  forever restartall
  exit
EOF
```

The testing is ok, but the deployment raises an error on `git pull`.
Should I do a `git commit -f` before the `git pull`?

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app.js
```

which is listed in the Jenkins console output. I don't understand why...

```
      ./script/test
   GET /
    ✓ respond with Hello Jenkins (41ms)
   1 passing (56ms)

  + ./script/deploy
  Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
  Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sat Jun 13 06:32:35 EDT 2015

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           74
  Usage of /:   9.1% of 19.56GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 25%               IP address for eth0: 46.101.165.112
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

38 packages can be updated.
17 updates are security updates.

Updating 784e256..a4095a8
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
[32minfo[39m:    Forever restarted processes:
[90mdata[39m:    [37m   [39m [37muid[39m  [90mcommand[39m             [90mscript[39m [37mforever[39m [37mpid[39m   [37mid[39m [35mlogfile[39m                     [33muptime[39m       
[90mdata[39m:    [0] uvyu [90m/usr/local/bin/node[39m [90mapp.js[39m 4271    13896    [35m/home/app/.forever/uvyu.log[39m [33m0:0:1:42.664[39m 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You met this error because you edited the `app.js` file locally. So if you execute command `git pull`, git will pull the latest update from the remote server and as a result, this action will overwrite your local version, so git throw out the error message:

```
   error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
app.js
```

You can either commit your local changes by issuing commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some msg here"
```

Or if you don't want to commit your local changes, then you can temporarily save your local changes by issuing command:

```
git stash
```

After quick read the link you pasted, I believe in your case, you should choose to `git commit` rather than `git stash`.